# Unable to send array in a object via ajax post request. Array is not basically visible in the object after the after post requestsuccess

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reactjs, post

This is the Object which used in Post request#

```
ProductBrandName: "asd"
ProductCatagoryMenOrWomen: "Men"
ProductDiscription: "asd"
ProductImages: Array(1)
0: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/
1: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

ProductName: "asd"
ProductPrice: "asd"
ProductType: "Shoes"
ProductUplodedDate: Wed Oct 14 2020 10:00:15{}
'''
```

After Post call, it is not displaying the array in the obj.
This is the obj after the post-call
I want an array in it

```
 {
    "id": "4",
    "ProductName": "asd",
    "ProductPrice": "asd",
    "ProductDiscription": "asd",
    "ProductCatagoryMenOrWomen": "Men",
    "ProductBrandName": "asd",
    "ProductUplodedDate": "Wed Oct 14 2020 10:00:15 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "ProductType": "Shoes"
  }
```

This is the ajax call I am using to post it

```
 $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"https://5f844e4d6b9744002.mockapi.io/ShopingWebSit",
            data:product
        })
```

Comment: If possible, explain a bit more what the problem is?